# Composer replace no longer working for Magento Cloud 2.4.3

Tags: magento2, composer, magento-cloud, composer-update, composer.json

I was trying to setup a new Magento Cloud 2.4.3 project, and wanted to remove unnecessary module from the installation. I usually use [yireo/magento2-replace-all](https://github.com/yireo/magento2-replace-all) package to clear out some of the module which I will not be using for the project, it usually works without any issues.

But now with the new project getting this error whenever I am trying to use the composer replace node in my `composer.json` file

```bash
Dependency resolution completed in 0.004 seconds
Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.

  Problem 1
    - magento/magento-cloud-template is present at version 2.4.3 and cannot be modified by Composer
    - Only one of these can be installed: magento/module-wishlist-analytics[100.4.2], magento/magento-cloud-template[2.4.3]. magento/magento-cloud-template replaces magento/module-wishlist-analytics and thus cannot coexist with it.
    - magento/module-wishlist-analytics is locked to version 100.4.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
```

My `composer.json` looks like

```json
...
"replace": {
   "magento/magento-cloud-template": "*",
   "astock/stock-api-libphp": "*",
   "magento/adobe-stock-integration": "*",
   "magento/module-adobe-ims": "*",
   "magento/module-adobe-ims-api": "*",
   "magento/module-adobe-stock-admin-ui": "*",
   "magento/module-adobe-stock-asset": "*",
   "magento/module-adobe-stock-asset-api": "*",
   "magento/module-adobe-stock-client": "*",
   "magento/module-adobe-stock-client-api": "*",
   "magento/module-adobe-stock-image": "*",
   "magento/module-adobe-stock-image-admin-ui": "*",
   "magento/module-adobe-stock-image-api": "*",
   "magento/google-shopping-ads": "*",
   "magento/module-advanced-pricing-import-export": "*",
   "magento/module-amqp": "*",
   "magento/module-amqp-store": "*",
   "magento/module-analytics": "*",
   "magento/module-authorizenet": "*",
   "magento/module-authorizenet-acceptjs": "*",
   "magento/module-authorizenet-cardinal": "*",
   "magento/module-authorizenet-graph-ql": "*",
   "magento/module-bundle-import-export": "*",
   "magento/module-catalog-analytics": "*",
   "magento/module-cardinal-commerce": "*",
   "magento/module-customer-analytics": "*",
   "magento/module-customer-finance": "*",
   "magento/module-customer-import-export": "*",
   "magento/module-cybersource": "*",
   "magento/module-dhl": "*",
   "magento/module-downloadable-import-export": "*",
   "magento/module-eway": "*",
   "magento/module-fedex": "*",
   "magento/module-google-adwords": "*",
   "magento/module-google-optimizer": "*",
   "magento/module-grouped-import-export": "*",
   "magento/module-marketplace": "*",
   "magento/module-multishipping": "*",
   "magento/module-new-relic-reporting": "*",
   "magento/module-page-builder-analytics": "*",
   "magento/module-quote-analytics": "*",
   "magento/module-review-analytics": "*",
   "magento/module-sales-analytics": "*",
   "magento/module-sample-data": "*",
   "magento/module-send-friend": "*",
   "magento/module-send-friend-graph-ql": "*",
   "magento/module-signifyd": "*",
   "magento/module-swagger": "*",
   "magento/module-swagger-webapi": "*",
   "magento/module-swagger-webapi-async": "*",
   "magento/module-tax-import-export": "*",
   "magento/module-ups": "*",
   "magento/module-usps": "*",
   "magento/module-version": "*",
   "magento/module-wishlist-analytics": "*",
   "magento/module-worldpay": "*"
}
...
```

Anyone has any idea what might be the new process of getting ride of unwanted modules using composer ?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: Try disabling those modules first by running bin/magento module:disable command.